# Filter grouped Pandas data frame by column aggregate, when groups are from a MultiIndex level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

How can I drop data from one level of a multi-level indexed data frame, based on aggregated information I get from a column within a groupby on that level?

For example, with data frame `dfmi`:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A0','A1','A2'], ['B0','B1','B2']], names=["index_1", "index_2"])
columns = ['foo', 'bar']
dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(18).reshape((len(midx), len(columns))),
                    index=midx, columns=columns)

dfmi
                 foo  bar
index_1 index_2          
A0      B0         0    1
        B1         2    3
        B2         4    5
A1      B0         6    7
        B1         8    9
        B2        10   11
A2      B0        12   13
        B1        14   15
        B2        16   17
```

Let's say I only want to keep levels of `index_1` if the mean for `foo` exceeds a certain threshold.
Like this:

```
thresh = 5

for grp, data in dfmi.groupby("index_1"):
    print(data.foo.mean() > thresh)

False  <-- drop this level
True
True
```

Desired output:

```
                 foo  bar
index_1 index_2          
A1      B0         6    7
        B1         8    9
        B2        10   11
A2      B0        12   13
        B1        14   15
        B2        16   17
```

In this toy example I can get what I want with `dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice["A1":"A2", :]]`.  But I can't figure out how to use `IndexSlice` or `loc` variants to do aggregations inside a grouped MultiIndex and then slice the full data frame based on the results.

My best solution so far is to just keep track of the level values that qualify as keepers (with `grp`), and then use the accumulated `keepers` collection with `IndexSlice`:

```
keepers = list()

for grp, data in dfmi.groupby("index_1"):
    if data.foo.mean() > thresh:
        keepers.append(grp)

dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[keepers, :]]
```

I'm looking for a more efficient and/or more elegant way to accomplish that with native Pandas functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loc` once you have created your mask, like so:

```
mask = dfmi.groupby(level=0)['foo'].mean()>thresh

dfmi.loc[mask.index[mask]]
```

Yields:

```
index_1 index_2          
A1      B0         6    7
        B1         8    9
        B2        10   11
A2      B0        12   13
        B1        14   15
        B2        16   17
```

Comment: That's very nice.   Thank you.

Comment: +1 `dfmi[dfmi.groupby('index_1')['foo'].transform('mean') > thresh]` a different way using boolean indexing